# The process cannot access the file after submitting to SendEmail()

Tags: asp.net, filelock

I create an XML file that I need to email to users when they register.
After creating the XML file I pass it as an attached filename (with ServeMapPath) and the email programs send the email message with file. Yea.  However, I then want to delete that file.

It appears the SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(settings.SMTPServer); is locking the file after sending email.  Even if I wait a long time, it remains locked.  Using IISExpress from Visual Studio.  If I exist Visual Studio and reopen debugging, I can then delete, or overwrite the file one time.

Is this a characteristic of developing under Visual Studio or ??? any work arounds for testing?  Will IIS keep the file locked on a production server?

Answer (score 1):

Do I earn points for finding the solution to my own problem?

The email send routine creates a connection to SMTPClient, and I created a new Message as well.  I did a client.Dispose(), but not for the message.  When I did some clean up, like message.Dispose(), the file unlocked and my application could then delete it when done.

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(settings.SMTPServer);
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
....
 //send message with attachment
....
client.Dispose();
message.Dispose();
```

I hope this helps others.

Comment: You got the reputations for finding solution to your question,+1!